# Using LS for a specific path & file type without returing full file path?

Tags: linux, bash, ls

I am writing a bash script and would like to use LS giving it a path/*.tar and have it return just file names instead of full path and file name to pass the file names through read into an array, below is what happens in terminal:

#### If i just use LS with a directory it returns:

```
admin@linuxbox:~$ ls  /home/admin/Backup/
0_BuIndex.txt.backup  Backup1376238064.tar  Backup1376239611.tar  Backup1376241919.tar
Backup1376167035.tar  Backup1376238960.tar  Backup1376240158.tar  Backup1376243097.tar
Backup1376168581.tar  Backup1376239110.tar  Backup1376241421.tar
Backup1376237070.tar  Backup1376239350.tar  Backup1376241489.tar
Backup1376237928.tar  Backup1376239479.tar  Backup1376241608.tar
```

#### Giving path & file type it returns:

```
admin@linuxbox:~$ ls  /home/admin/Backup/*.tar
/home/admin/Backup/Backup1376167035.tar  /home/admin/Backup/Backup1376239479.tar
/home/admin/Backup/Backup1376168581.tar  /home/admin/Backup/Backup1376239611.tar
/home/admin/Backup/Backup1376237070.tar  /home/admin/Backup/Backup1376240158.tar
/home/admin/Backup/Backup1376237928.tar  /home/admin/Backup/Backup1376241421.tar
/home/admin/Backup/Backup1376238064.tar  /home/admin/Backup/Backup1376241489.tar
/home/admin/Backup/Backup1376238960.tar  /home/admin/Backup/Backup1376241608.tar
/home/admin/Backup/Backup1376239110.tar  /home/admin/Backup/Backup1376241919.tar
/home/admin/Backup/Backup1376239350.tar  /home/admin/Backup/Backup1376243097.tar
```

I would like to use a command like the second but have it only return the file names without the path, my work around right now is to use

```
read -r -a TarArray <<< `ls -1 /home/admin/Backup | grep "tar"`
```

but I am hoping to find a solution that doesn't require me to pipe through grep.

Any ideas? Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could potentially use `find` for this :

```
find /home/admin/Backup -name \*.tar -printf '%f\n'
```

From the man page :

```
-printf format
    True;  print  format  on  the standard output,
    interpreting `\' escapes and `%' directives.
    ...
    %f     File's name with any leading directories
           removed (only the last element).
```

Answer (score 2):

So I know the answer has already been chosen but here is an option for using `ls` just in case you were curious:

```
ls /home/admin/Backup/*.tar | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the `ls` command from the directory:

```
( cd /home/admin/Backup ; ls *.tar )
```

But you really don't need to use the `ls` command for this. The shell already expands the `*tar` wildcard for you; all `ls` does in this case is print the arguments. So:

```
( cd /home/admin/Backup ; echo *.tar )
```

(Incidentally, your command with `grep "tar"` will list all files with `"tar"` anywhere in their names, not just files whose names end in `.tar`. If you wanted to use `grep`, you'd want `grep '\.tar$'`.)

Answer (score 0):

You [should not use `ls` for this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Instead, simply create an array with the full names:

```
files=(/path/to/dir/*.tar)
```

... and run `basename` on each element when you process the array.

Comment: I like your solution but it would require a rework of a good deal of code, but thanks next time I am doing something similar I will keep this in mind. Thanks!